# Calculating a Rolling Sum Based on Row

Tags: mysql, rolling-computation

I am attempting to calculate the rolling sum of two columns 'Weight' and 'Volume' between the current row and the previous 4 rows based on the DateTime row. These are loads of logs, and some days we get multiple loads. So essentially, every time a new load comes in, it will calculate a new rolling sum based on itself and the previous 4 rows. I am using MySQL 5.7. Keep in mind that each row is NOT a new date. The data should look something like this...

```
         DateTime       | Weight | Volume | Roll_Weight | Roll_Volume
    2019-01-01 08:00:00 | 54000  | 72.2   |   54000     |   72.2
    2019-01-01 09:30:00 | 29000  | 38.0   |   83000     |  110.2
    2019-01-05 13:00:00 | 38900  | 54.8   |  118900     |  165.0 
    2019-01-06 07:00:00 | 44000  | 56.2   |  162900     |  221.2
    2019-01-06 12:30:00 | 49000  | 18.0   |  211900     |  239.2
    2019-01-07 09:00:00 | 27900  | 84.5   |  185800     |  251.5
    2019-01-10 08:00:00 | 94000  | 72.6   |  250800     |  286.1
    2019-01-10 13:30:00 | 65000  | 39.7   |  286800     |  271.0
    2019-01-10 15:00:00 | 38900  | 50.5   |  274800     |  265.3
```

```
Select DateTime, Sum(Weight), Sum(Volume) over (Partition by DateTime ORDER BY DateTime asc 4 preceding)
From t1
```

I am aware that, because I am using MySQL 5.7, I do not have the capability to use OVER, but this appears to be what I need. What is the best way to get around this issue? All of the resources I have found have a different date for every row, so they just use a self join query on date, but I can't do that because I am going by rolling by row.

Answer (score 0):

We can `COALESCE` the previous 4 values for **Weight** and **Volume** by **DateTime** and then `+` them up with the respective current values

```
SELECT `DateTime`, Weight, Volume,
   Weight + 
   COALESCE((SELECT Weight 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 0, 1), 0) +
   COALESCE((SELECT Weight 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1, 1), 0)+
   COALESCE((SELECT Weight 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 2, 1), 0)+
   COALESCE((SELECT Weight 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 3, 1), 0) AS RollWeight,

   Volume + 
   COALESCE((SELECT Volume 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 0, 1), 0) +
   COALESCE((SELECT Volume 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `Date` DESC LIMIT 1, 1), 0)+
   COALESCE((SELECT Volume 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 2, 1), 0)+
   COALESCE((SELECT Volume 
             FROM t1 AS t2
             WHERE t2.`DateTime` < t3.`DateTime`
             ORDER BY `DateTime` DESC LIMIT 3, 1), 0) AS RollVolume

FROM t1 AS t3;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. When I run this query, it only outputs 4 rows of data, and the SUM columns do not contain the sum, but rather just the weight and volume for that row.

Comment: @FulcrumFlex17 You're right. I've edited my answer to use a different approach where we select the last 4 values and then add them up to get the running sum